# Why lightning:fileUpload doesn't work on public sites?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, force.com-sites

I'm using `lightning:fileUpload` inside a lightning component and I'm testing it on a public site, but when I attach a file/files the modal box with the `Done` button doesn't show up. When I'm testing that component in the salesforce app builder is running as expected. Why that could happen?

```
                <lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt"
                                      name="fileUploader"
                                      multiple="true"
                                      accept=".pdf, .png"
                                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                      onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" >
                </lightning:fileUpload>
```

That means that the `onuploadfinished` function never executes. The same thing happens if you try to put an HTML tag inside the component (for ex. iframe, input type="file").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation), for the community site user, we need to enable the org preference **Allow site guest users to upload files**. To enable this, go to Setup > General Settings, and select Allow site guest users to upload files. One more thing this component is not supported in Lightning Out or standalone apps, and displays as a disabled input. So if your site using lightning out to use this component then this will not work.

Comment: My app is a standalone app. How can I make the upload function work there? I tried to create a VFP and interact with the component through message exchange, but the VFP is never loaded inside the iframe, because HTML tags never rendered.

Comment: If you read the document correctly, it mentioned `This component is not supported in Lightning Out or standalone apps, and displays as a disabled input. `

Comment: Yeah, I understood, I asked if there is any other way to do that? How can I let a user upload a file from a standalone app?

Comment: You can create a custom lightning component for this and can take help from this example http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/09/25/file-upload-lightning-component/

Answer (score 1):

Did the same problem when trying to use LWC file upload on Salesforce sites
why can't I use 'markup: // forceContent / *' in `<aura: dependency>` of my `<aura: application>`,
so I can't use `<lightning-file-upload>`.

The solution for me was to create my own file upload, maybe it will help you or help someone ...

//HTML

```
<lightning-input type="file" label="File Upload" onchange={saveFileHandle}></lightning-input>
```

//JavaScript

```
saveFileHandle(event){
    let fileList = event.detail.files;

    [...fileList].forEach(file => {
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        file.sObjectId = this.leadId;

        fileReader.onload = function() {
            let fileContents = fileReader.result;
            let base64Mark = 'base64,';
            let dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64Mark) + base64Mark.length;
            fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);

            saveFile({
                parentId: file.sObjectId,
                fileName: file.name,
                base64Data: encodeURIComponent(fileContents)
            })
            .then(result => {
                alert('Sucess');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert('Error');
            });
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

//Controller Apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void saveFile(Id parentId, String fileName, String base64Data) { 
    base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');

    //Insert ContentVersion
    ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion();
    contentVersion.ContentLocation = 'S'; //S-Document is in Salesforce. E-Document is outside of Salesforce. L-Document is on a Social Netork.
    contentVersion.PathOnClient = fileName;//File name with extention
    contentVersion.Origin = 'C';//C-Content Origin. H-Chatter Origin.
    contentVersion.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();//Owner of the file
    contentVersion.Title = fileName;//Name of the file
    contentVersion.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);//File content
    Insert contentVersion;

    //After saved the Content Verison, get the ContentDocumentId
    Id contentDocumentId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:contentVersion.Id].ContentDocumentId;

    //Insert ContentDocumentLink
    ContentDocumentLink contentDocumentLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    contentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId = contentDocumentId;//Add ContentDocumentId
    contentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId = parentId;//Add attachment parentId
    contentDocumentLink.ShareType = 'I';//V - Viewer permission. C - Collaborator permission. I - Inferred permission.
    contentDocumentLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers';//AllUsers, InternalUsers, SharedUsers
    Insert contentDocumentLink;
}
```

You can adapt your code to the .